# Are negative prefixes valid in braces?

Tags: negative-prefixes, braces

This is a question about grammar, in particular about a specific language syntax.

In the german langage it's legit to write negative prefixes in braces like

"Die JSON (De-)Serialisation wurde implementiert."

Is this valid in english?

"The JSON (de-)serialization has been implemented."

As a software developer I need to document the work I've done and the software functionality itself. I often have a lot of language constructs similar to the one above. And if it's legit to use this syntax of negative prefixes it would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Do you want it to mean "both the JSON serialization and deserialization have been implemented"?

Comment: Yes, I do. And I fixed `has` to `have` right now.

Comment: Actually, I think "has" is grammatically the correct verb there.

Comment: If you use the brackets you are suggesting that both versions (negative and positive) are valid.

Comment: @Gio Yes I do. But is this grammatically valid?

Comment: This example is one of those that beg for the redundancy of "The JSON serialization and deserialization have been implemented." Quicker to read than rereading the original three times.

Comment: Such a usage is probably not 'forbidden', but it is ambiguous, in spite of the hyphen. Is use of the prefix a short cut to 'serialization and deserialization', or is it a correction, perhaps whimsical, of a misnomer? _His (ab)use of the English language_ (note that proper  nouns and proper adjectives are spelled with capitals).

Comment: There's no law against it, although editors and style guides may not like it. I'd imagine it's possible in very technical publications (manuals, software documentation, etc) but wouldn't expect to use it in most professionally-edited text. The only guiding principle is whether it's comprehensible. (This seems to be more a matter of opinion than fact.)

Comment: Parentheses are often used for this purpose in English (although, as has been pointed out, some may perceive that as somewhat informal), but, when they are so used, a hyphen is not necessary (unless the longer term is itself hyphenated). Notice that Mr. Ashworth used *(ab)use* in his example, not *(ab-)use*.

Comment: @jsw29 Thank you for beeing precise. And if the question may be reopened it would be nice you write it as an answere I could mark as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of parentheses to denote a prefix, as in '(de-)serialization', is not strictly incorrect. It's clear in its meaning and would likely be understood by most readers.

However, it's worth noting that this usage is not common in formal written English. It's more frequently seen in informal contexts or in technical writing, where brevity and conciseness are prioritized. In more formal or polished writing, it would generally be preferable to fully write out both options, as in 'serialization and deserialization'.

That being said, the most important consideration in any piece of writing should be the intended audience. If you're writing for a technical audience who would appreciate the brevity and clarity of the '(de-)serialization' construction, then by all means, use it. If you're writing for a broader or more general audience, it might be better to err on the side of traditional usage.

In either case, the ultimate goal should be clear, effective communication. If the '(de-)' prefix achieves that goal for your intended audience, then it is 'valid' in the most important sense